# msbuild.exe is not respecting LinkLibraryDependencies

Tags: msbuild, devenv

I'm upgrading a Visual Studio solution from 2008 to 2013. Due to licencing issues I'll be using msbuild.exe, instead of devenv.com, on our build servers.

But I've hit a linking error which appears to be specific to msbuild.exe. i.e. When built with devenv.com there is no issue.

Debugging into the problem I discovered a difference between the link commands. The project (testA) that gives the error depends upon a project (projectA). This dependency is setup in the Visual Studio 2013 **Project Dependencies/Project References**.

But we don't want testA to use this approach to link against projectA (we have an alternative mechanism to do the linking). So the **Link Library Dependencies** attribute of **Project Reference Properties** is set to False. In the .vcxproj that looks like

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\projectA.vcxproj">
  <Project>{472cd426-5c95-4f53-97f8-bf7c4425d1d4}</Project>
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  <Private>true</Private>
  <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>false</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
  <LinkLibraryDependencies>false</LinkLibraryDependencies>
  <UseLibraryDependencyInputs>false</UseLibraryDependencyInputs>
</ProjectReference>
```

For Visual Studio 2013 (aka devenv.com) that is fine. projectA is not linked.

But msbuild.exe does not respect this property. On the command line I see it link with projectA.lib. That gives the following error

```
error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall projectA::mymethod(void)const "
(?ismethod@projectA@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in myobject.obj
```

Is this a known issue. Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you do not want to link against projectA, maybe you do not need a project reference for it?

Comment: TestA links against ProjectA's .obj files. This allows the tests to execute and check code that is normally hidden. So we have to be sure the .obj files are created before TestA's link step.

Comment: msbuild's metaproj generator appears to turn solution project dependencies into ProjectReferences. This means there's an additional set of project references to deal with, and I haven't found out yet when exactly msbuild uses this reference over the one you have in the real project.